# nodejs es6 way of running task every second for 10 seconds

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to come up with an elegant implementation for an `async` function that attempts a check operation `check()` every `t` seconds for a maximum `n` number of times; i.e. I would like to immediately return if `check() === true`, otherwise I would like to bail out after `t * n` seconds (`n` attempts).

I have a working implementation using counter-based for-loop and simple delay:

```
// doc and pair are defined already
let delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                                                    
  if (doc.key) {
    break
  }                                                       
  await delay(1000)                                                               
  doc = await DbModel.findOne(pair)                                                                                                       
}
```

Is there a better way of achieving this using native es6 features (e.g. perhaps promisified versions of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`)?

Comment: I'm no expert, but as far as I know, those are your options.

Comment: Why use a promise when all you need is the timeout? Also remember that a timeout doesn’t guarantee the timing.

Comment: So you think the implementation above is just fine? I understand your second point and acknowledge that.

Comment: You mention ES6 native features which confuses me as setTimeout is a part of the ES6 spec. It does what you require and is fairly simple.

Comment: What I had in mind as a potential alternative implementation was a way of mixing `setInterval` and `setTimeout` to get rid of the for loop. Not sure if that would be a nicer implementation but being somewhat new to the language, I don't trust in the patterns I use.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [node-scheduer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule). Very much similar to the cronjob. But the application must be kept on running.

It executes an event on a given interval. Make sure the job is executed after the desired interval every time and Put the repeated functionality there.

Comment: Thanks. I just checkout the package but feel it is a bit of an overkill for my use case. I was mostly wondering if there is a better native pattern out there that I am not aware of.